# Unable to add time-dependent trigger to workflow rule

Tags: workflow, configuration, time-dependent-workflow

I have a workflow rule with a time-dependent trigger on it.  It's been working fine for years.  I now have a requirement to add an additional time-dependent trigger to the workflow rule.

I disabled the workflow rule, clicked edit, but the button "Add Time Trigger" is disabled.  I went to my Sandbox environment to try and reproduce the issue, but I was able to add the second time trigger to that workflow rule.

How can I add an additional time trigger?

[image: Time trigger button disabled]

**Edit**: After RTFM, I found this:

> You can't add or remove time triggers if the workflow rule is deactivated but has pending actions in the queue.

I certainly don't want to remove all of the pending actions; many of those are e-mails that need to be sent out to customers.  Is my only way around this problem to create an identical (duplicate) workflow rule?

Comment: Short answer is "Yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that there were actions in the queue.  From the Salesforce docs:

> You can't add or remove time triggers if the workflow rule is
>   deactivated but has pending actions in the queue.

Comment: Just excountering the same issue... can you clarify, where can I see the pending actions ?